# SQL select from two tables with union dont get right column name

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to select data from two tables, `category` and `sub_category`.

But I only get the column names of `category`. I want both `category` and `sub_category`.

Here is the result:

```
  { category_id: 3, category: 'GARDEN' },
  { category_id: 6, category: 'ART' },
  { category_id: 4, category: 'CONSOLE' },
  { category_id: 2, category: 'ELECTRONICS' },
  { category_id: 4, category: 'ELECTRONICS' },
  { category_id: 2, category: 'CONSOLE' },
  { category_id: 5, category: 'CHAIR' },
  { category_id: 6, category: 'COLORS' },
  { category_id: 5, category: 'GARDEN' },
  { category_id: 1, category: 'CONSOLE' },
  { category_id: 3, category: 'CUT' },
  { category_id: 1, category: 'ELECTRONICS' }
```

Here is my code:

```
SELECT
    c.id AS category_id,
    c.category
FROM 
    category c

UNION

SELECT 
    sc.id AS sub_category_id,
    sc.sub_category
FROM 
    sub_category sc
```

€:

here is my expected result:

```
  { category_id: 3, category: 'GARDEN' },
  { category_id: 6, category: 'ART' },
  { category_id: 4, category: 'CONSOLE' },
  { category_id: 2, category: 'ELECTRONICS' },
  { category_id: 4, category: 'ELECTRONICS' },
  { category_id: 2, category: 'CONSOLE' },
  { category_id: 5, category: 'CHAIR' },
  { category_id: 6, category: 'COLORS' },
  { sub_category_id: 5, category: 'GARDEN' },
  { sub_category_id: 1, category: 'CONSOLE' },
  { sub_category_id: 3, category: 'CUT' },
  { sub_category_id: 1, category: 'ELECTRONICS' }
```

Comment: Are you asking how to do a [join](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp)?

Comment: Why I need join ? I mean in join I have to set example s.user_id = a.user_id but in my case both tables have no references to each other so this works with join ?

Comment: Can you share what outcome you expect?

Usually in a case like that I would assume that sub_category has a parent relationship to category. That means usually your sub_category table would include another field "category_id" which matches an id in your category table. Then you can use a join like scrhartley mentioned, and you could output all 4 fields.

If your goal is to just have one flat list of categories and sub categories, then you would have to ensure for a UNION that the field names and data types are the same for both tables (e.g. by naming the 2nd field simply "name".

Comment: Please read and follow https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: The `UNION` returns **ONE** result set - and the column name in that result set **CANNOT** change in the middle of it. It's defined by the first part of the `UNION` query.

Comment: Is something of this what you want? https://dbfiddle.uk/5u8qbvZK

Comment: @JonasMetzler yes exaclty this thank you!

Comment: What of this? I used two different queries ;)

Comment: @JonasMetzler the first one :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comments are right in recommending a [`join`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-FROM):

> `FULL OUTER JOIN` returns all the joined rows, plus one row for each unmatched left-hand row (extended with nulls on the right), plus one row for each unmatched right-hand row (extended with nulls on the left).

You can instruct it to *not match* and just show all unmatched rows from both tables: [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/oJ0yZgi7)

```sql
SELECT
    c.id AS category_id,
    c.category,
    sc.id AS sub_category_id,
    sc.sub_category AS sub_category
FROM 
    category c FULL OUTER JOIN sub_category sc ON false
ORDER BY category_id, sub_category_id, category, sub_category;
```

| category_id | category | sub_category_id | sub_category |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | CONSOLE | *null* | *null* |
| 2 | ELECTRONICS | *null* | *null* |
| 3 | GARDEN | *null* | *null* |
| 4 | CONSOLE | *null* | *null* |
| 4 | ELECTRONICS | *null* | *null* |
| 5 | CHAIR | *null* | *null* |
| 6 | ART | *null* | *null* |
| 6 | COLORS | *null* | *null* |
| *null* | *null* | 1 | CONSOLE |
| *null* | *null* | 1 | ELECTRONICS |
| *null* | *null* | 3 | CUT |
| *null* | *null* | 5 | GARDEN |

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are using a **UNION** operation, which combines the results of two queries vertically, but it discards the column names from the second query and renames the columns based on the first query.

You should use a JOIN operation instead!

```
SELECT
    c.id as category_id,
    c.category,
    sc.id as sub_category_id,
    sc.sub_category
FROM
    category c
JOIN
    sub_category sc ON c.id = sc.category_id;
```

Comment: but what is when sc.category_id not exists in c.id ? you say c.id = sc.category but not all sub_category have the same id as category id

Comment: How about a left join in that case then?

Comment: Scroll down to look at the Venn diagrams to get some idea of the [different join types](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp). This shows how each join deals with not finding matches in the opposite table.

Comment: not working with left join, I had 6 categories and 6 sub_categories now I added one more to sub categories now I have 6 categories and 7 sub categories but it shows only 6 not the 7th because they have no common to other table

Comment: Tbh it would be helpful if you can share what outcome you are expecting. By the looks of it maybe you are looking for a FULL OUTER JOIN.

Comment: @Hassoo I added my expected result

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be able to differentiate what table the rows came from in a `UNION` statement, you can e.g. add a separate column to your result set to specify that - something like this:

```
SELECT
    c.id AS category_id,
    c.category,
    'Category' AS source_table
FROM 
    category c

UNION

SELECT 
    sc.id,
    sc.sub_category,
    'Subcategory' AS source_table
FROM 
    sub_category sc
```

Then the result you get will contain either `Category` or `Subcategory` in the new `source_table` column to tell you where the row came from.